Determining the LRT test, the rejection region and the p-value.
Good morning everyone,
I need to solve this problem, but I can't find the solution for the last step:
Let there be a sample id $X_1,X_2, . . . ,X_n$, drawn from a population with density:
$f(x,θ)= \frac{\theta}{x^2}$
with $x> θ$ and $θ> 0$
(a) Determine the likelihood ratio test and its critical region for the following assumptions: 
$H_0: θ \le 2$ versus $H_1:θ > 2$ 
when $n = 10$ and $α = 0.05$.
(b) Determine the p-value corresponding to the following sample realization:\
$1.99$ $2.56$ $2.37$ $1.66$ $3.50$ $1.72$ $8.42$ $10.76$ $5.48$ $3.93$
Thanks to other posts, I was able to determine the likelihood ratio test, given by:
$λ(x)= \frac{1}{[min(x)^n]} $
and the critical region is:
$R ≡ {(x_1,\cdots x_{10}) : λ(x)\ge C^\frac{-1}{10}  }$
but I don't understand how to calculate the critical region (especially the value of $C$) or the p-value.
Can anyone help me?
